# Passing React component multiple classes

Tags: reactjs, class, svg, components, children

I want to move two svg icons in the opposite direction at the same time. My component can use one, but not two classes. How can I make my code work so that it accepts both classes that I give to my component.

React code:

```
const [arrowPos, setArrowPos] = useState(false)

function arrowToggle() {
   setArrowPos(!arrowPos)
      }
const arrowUp = arrowPos ? 'arrow-path-1' : ''
const arrowDown = arrowPos ? 'arrow-path-2' : ''
```

The component I want to use:

```
//THIS WORKS WITH ONE CLASS
import React from 'react';

const Arrow = ({className}) => {
  return (
    <svg width="32px" height="32px" stroke="green" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path className={className} d="M 4.21875 10.78125 L 2.78125 12.21875 L 15.28125 24.71875 L 16 25.40625 L 16.71875 24.71875 L 29.21875 12.21875 L 27.78125 10.78125 L 16 22.5625 Z"/>
      <path d="M 4.21875 10.78125 L 2.78125 12.21875 L 15.28125 24.71875 L 16 25.40625 L 16.71875 24.71875 L 29.21875 12.21875 L 27.78125 10.78125 L 16 22.5625 Z"/>
    </svg>
  );
}
export default Arrow;

//THIS DOESN'T WITH TWO
    import React from 'react';
    const Arrow = ({className, className2}) => {
      return (
        <svg width="32px" height="32px" stroke="green" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path className={className} d="M 4.21875 10.78125 L 2.78125 12.21875 L 15.28125 24.71875 L 16 25.40625 L 16.71875 24.71875 L 29.21875 12.21875 L 27.78125 10.78125 L 16 22.5625 Z"/>
          <path className={className2} d="M 4.21875 10.78125 L 2.78125 12.21875 L 15.28125 24.71875 L 16 25.40625 L 16.71875 24.71875 L 29.21875 12.21875 L 27.78125 10.78125 L 16 22.5625 Z"/>
        </svg>
      );
    }
    export default Arrow;
```

Where I want to use it:

```
<div onClick={arrowToggle}>
     <Arrow className = {arrowUp, arrowDown}/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-path-1 {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.arrow-path-2 {
    transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code:

```
<Arrow className = {arrowUp, arrowDown}/>
```

Is wrong. It should be

```
<Arrow className={arrowUp} className2={arrowDown}/>
```

Comment: Indeed. It works, thank you!